# IIS 7 Dynamic Compression: would that make Content-Length header unpredictable?

Tags: iis-7, compression, outputstream, content-length

Using .NET 4.0 on IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 R2.

I would like to output a binary content which represents various types of documents (images, PDF, Office files, etc). Let's assume the entire content is already in a MemoryStream, I would like to output it by:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileNameSaveAs));
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", memoryStr.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.OutputStream.Write(memoryStr.ToArray(), 0, (int) memoryStr.Length);
Response.Flush();
```

The code above is not reliable. There are often file corruption. The clients using various browsers, sometimes have an aborted download, sometimes download a file which is unreadable. The likelihood of having a corruption increases with the file size. Using fiddler, we found out that the response header reported a content length different than the original file size. So for a quick test we commented out the line Response.AddHeader("Content-Length" ...) and the corruption issue disappeared.

Q1: Is this issue caused by the Dynamic Compression (enabled on IIS7 by default)?

Q2: If answer to Q1 is yes, then is there any elegant solution to inform the client about the Content-Length?

Q3: Removing the "Content-Length" header seems to affect the ability of the client to save file as. Example: "Content-Disposition", is initalized with fileNameSaveAs = "One Two Three.pdf". Using Firefox, when receiving the file, the download dialog defaulted to "One" as filename. Is it a normal consequence?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

made more tests, clarified a few things but not technically satisfactory.

A1. IIS 7.5 Dynamic Compression is not the cause. Download corruption still occurred whether Dynamic Compression, Static Compression, or both is disabled. As soon as the line Response.AddHeader("Content-Length" ... is commented out in the code. All download issue disappeared.

A2. no idea! I really would like to know.

A3. This behavior is probably a Firefox bug. This has nothing to do with the "Content-Length" header.